# Managed code library gets unloaded

Tags: asp.net, unmanaged, libraries, managed

I have this rather weird situation that I don't really know how to word it properly...

**The situation is like this:**

I have an ASP.NET Web application (WA). It references an assembly (CL1) that makes calls to a Unmanaged Dynamic Library (DLL). This DLL references a method from another library (LIB) which in its turn makes calls to a managed code class library (CL2).

So the chain is like this: `WA -> CL1 -> DLL -> LIB -> CL2`

I start my web application in the debug mode. Everything works fine. I see a page in the browser that shows the result (let's say a certain non-empty string) that is obtained from the last class library, CL2.
Now I check out a file in my web application in TFS. Visual Studio doesn't stop the debugging process, but, as I assume, it unloads the application, kills the session, etc.

I go to the browser and refresh the page - the application gets restarted, the page is being rendered, but turns out the call from LIB to CL2 doesn't work anymore. Instead of the string I get a bad pointer.

When I stop debugging and start it again (hard restart?) - everything starts working as it suppose to.

I assume that after my application ended and then started again (soft restart?), it failed to reload my CL2 for some reason.

**My question:** *Is there any way to prevent that?*